# Amazon Cloud Front - Changing the origin domain

Tags: cdn, amazon-cloudfront

Currently have a Cloudfront CDN with an **Origin** pointed to `http://mysite.com`. The CDN URL is  something like *jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net*. Currently there are a lot of external consumers of a file hosted on my site and access it via Cloudfront ( e.g. `http://jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net/files/library.js`) so it's important that CDN URL remains the same.

I would like to change the origin (`external.mysite.com` - which will include the same files and file structure) and I was wondering if this type of change would effect the **Domain Name** used by amazon (`jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net`)?

I am assuming this will work, but given the number of people relying on the file I thought it would be a good idea to check before proceeding.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you having the content on the CDN accessed by using the `jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net` host name?

The usual way is to not expose the cloudfront server name, but add a CNAME entry to your DNS to point requests for CDN content to something like `media.mysite.com`

```
media.mysite.com   CNAME   jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net
```

Cloudfront is notified of this CNAME and then this allows all the content linking to be served as something out of your own domain.

Back to the original question about changing the ORIGIN from `mysite.com` to `www.mysite.com` or `example.com`. As long as you aren't setting up a new Distribution, but only changing the ORIGIN for the existing distribution, you will be keeping the same Amazon assigned domain name, so `jr27a8vopf32a.cloudfront.net` will remain the same and be available, but will pull the content from the new ORIGIN.